# 14.04 stop Xhost running at login

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Anyone know how to stop xhost running at login for cli logins?

all it gives is "xhost:  unable to open display """ error because theres no Xserver running on this system.

Regards,
A

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have an unconditional  `xhost` in your `~/.bashrc`.

The problem is that `xhost` tries to communicate with the X server that owns the current "X display".

CLI executions don't have a current "X display", thus the error message from `xhost`.

You can check for the existence of the pointer to the current "X display" the same was `xhost` does, only in `bash`, and before calling `xhost`:

```
if [[ -n "$DISPLAY" ]] ; then
    xhost
fi
```

Comment: I neglected to check .bashrc I'd been to busy checking .profile thank-you.